# C# Ayuda con variables estaticas

Tags: c#

No tengo mucha experiencia con C# y Forms pero tengo un problema con las variables estaticas. Necesito que una variable int estatica defina el tamaño de un array estatico.

```
Public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        cont(Box.Text);
        }

        static int c = 0;

        static string[] elementos = new string[c+1];

        static void cont(string var1)
        {     
        elementos[c]= var1;
        MessageBox.Show(elementos[c]);
        c += 1;     
        }   

    }
```

Necesito que el static "int c = 0"  funcione como tamaño del array "static string[] elementos = new string[c +1]" pero arroja el siguiente error  "Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz."

¿Como logro que una variable static opere con otra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que crees que al definir el `array` usando otra variable, éste va a crecer cuando dicha variable crezca. Eso NO es así.

El tamaño del `array` se define cuando declaras la variable. En tu código, `elementos` SIEMPRE va a ser una `array` de tamaño 1.

Tienes varias opciones en este punto. Por un lado, si insistes en usar `Array`, puedes usar el método [`Array.Resize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2) para cambiar el tamaño. Yo es algo que no recomiendo nunca, ya que este método lo que hace es eliminar el array para volver a crearlo, y el rendimiento es bastante pobre.

Si lo que quieres es una colección que vaya creciendo a medida que vayas insertando elementos, hay muchas opciones mejores en .NET.

Lo mejor en este caso es usar [`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). En tu caso, define un `List<int>`

```
List<int> elementos= new List<int>();
void cont(string var1)
{     
    elementos.Add(var1);
    MessageBox.Show(elementos.Last());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aquí especificas que el tamaño de la variable **elementos** es 1.

```
static string[] elementos = new string[c];
```

Pero más adelante intentas meter un valor en el índice 1.

```
elementos[c]= var1;
```

El problema es que estás intentando meter un valor fuera del limite. Deberías hacer algo así:

```
elementos[c-1]= var1;
```

Ya que el índice de un array comienza en 0, no en 1 (como lo intentas hacer en tu código).

Comment: El codigo original era era c = 0 static string[] elementos = new string[c+1] ... pero tampoco funcionaba usandolo fuera de una funcion. arrojaba el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas que tu array sea de un tamaño indefinido sería mejor que utilizaras listas. Digamos que quieres usar un array de strings, en este caso declararías una lista así

```
List<String> lista = new List<String>();

Para agregar un elemento a la lista usarías

string cadena = "mi cadena";
lista.Ad(cadena);

para recorrer la lista lo puedes hacer con un foreach así

foreach(string str in lista)
{
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

Comment: El problema es que estoy usando forms, y necesito que se guarden los elementos almacenados den la lista pero cada vez que oprimo el boton, se reinicia todo el proceso y nada se guarda.. por eso necesito que se defina afuera con un static.

Comment: Si me muestras el código completo tal vez pueda ayudarte

Comment: El codigo muy largo pero basicamente necesesito que  el contador "c" y el array "elementos", se definan afuera de todas las funciones y que el contador "c" defina el tamaño de la lista, y funciona perfecto si los usas dentro de una funcion, pero si lo usas en la zona de "Public partial class Form1 : Form" deja de funcionar. Intente usando el estatic para definir el array y el contador pero el array no reconoce el valor del contador cuando se usa afuera de la funcion cont.. Por ello necesito saber como pueden interactuar dos variables definidas como static.